# log transform in linear model and exporting output to office

Tags: r

I have the following code for doing a linear regression:

```
data<-read.csv("File.csv",header=T)
trans<-log(data)
attach(trans)
outdata<-summary(lm(Y~A + B + C))
```

In the output what I have essentially is `log(y)=b0+b1*log(A)+b2*log(B)+b3*log(C)`. In the summary output, R gives me coefficients for the log(A), log(B), and log(C). However, I would like the coefficients for A, B, and C.  Is there a way to get R to give the output as 10^(b0), 10^(b1), and 10^(b2)?

Comment: @downvoter, if you're going to down vote, you should comment too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things here:

- The `log` function in R uses base `e` by default, so you *really* don't want to exponentiate the coefficients using base 10 after transforming the data using base `e`.
- The coefficients are accessible via `coef()` or the less recommended `outdata$coefficients[,1]`. You can extract them directly and then transform them if you like.
- Don't transform everything in `outdata$coefficients` and then print it. Most of the other information will end up nonsensical.

Comment: The `coef()` generic extractor function is recommended over directly accessing them. Less typing too :-)

Comment: ok so I would want to take the exponential of the coefficients after I get the output.  Are there any problems with this?

Comment: @J M - Depends on what you do with them! ;) This isn't the place for stats help, so I suggest you find some good books on linear models and if you have questions, try stats.stackexchange.com.